# What is the purpose of <asp:templatefield>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, coding-style, computer-science

It seems like there is `HeaderTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate` within the `TemplateField` at the code which I am examining.
What else can exists with `<asp:TemplateField>` apart from `HeaderTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 3):

They are in effect a means to "drop in" standard asp.net controls into quite a few of the data aware controls.

So, GridView, Datagrid, Repeater and a few more require this to allow dropping in of standard controls to render.

So, for a GridView, you can drop in plane jane asp.net controls, but to do so, you require to wrap those plane jane controls in what is called a "Template".

So, for a grid, you might see this:

[image]

Note the template field for a simple check box. So, when we run this, we get this:

[image]

So, the template has features like "HeaderText" etc.

However, if you use a newer ListView? Then you don't need to use Template fields, and if you only have say a few template fields, then a GridView is fine. However, if you have say a boatload of asp.net controls you want in that Grid, then I prefer a ListView.

So, this template field lets you define header text, formatting, justification etc.

For example, the above check box doesn’t look all that great. (not centered etc.).

```
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                            Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And now we get this:

[image]

So, for a data repeater, DataView, GridView and a few more, then they have built in data bound controls (BoundField), but often we want to use controls like a drop-down list, a picture, or whatever in the markup - so you have to wrap the plane jane asp.net control(s) each in a template field, and this lets you define the heading for the grid, the justification etc.

Comment: We can have FooterTemplate too I believe. This is a good question and I am subscribed to this. Wish you luck with your coding in Webforms!